# Regex parse group of numbers

Tags: c#, regex

What i have:

```
1. 25686-47362-04822-08149-48999-28161-15124-63556

2. 25686-47362-04822-08149-48999-28161-15124-6355654534

3. 54354325686-47362-04822-08149-48999-28161-15124-63556

4. 25686-47362-04822-08149-48999-28161-15124-6355654534fds

5. fdsfds54354325686-47362-04822-08149-48999-28161-15124-63556

6. 25686-47362-04822-08149-48999-28161-15124-63556-63556
```

What i expect to get

```
1. 25686-47362-04822-08149-48999-28161-15124-63556
```

I tried something nearest `([0-9]{5,5}){8}`

I trying to avoid 2,3,4,5,6.

Comment: What is the source? A string or a file? What is the environment? Perl, Grep, Python, Javascript, Vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
  string source = @"25686-47362-04822-08149-48999-28161-15124-63556";

  bool result = Regex.IsMatch(source, "^[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{5}){7}$");
```

Explanation:

```
  ^               anchor (beginning of the string)
  [0-9]{5}        5 digits group
  (-[0-9]{5}){7}  7 more groups of 5 digits
  $               anchor (ending of the string)
```

Comment: Very nice, Dima, that is the right style. Unroll the expression where you can, and keep the quantified group at the end of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is a way to ask for it to "repeat" the grouping, but i would type it like that:

```
/^([0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{5})/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
^\d+\.\s(\d{5}-?){8}$
```

It matches a whole line that matches your criteria: A digit or more, a dot, a whitespace, 8 blocks à 5 digits with hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

You can qualify that line with:

```
/^((?:\D|^)\d{5}){8}$/m
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GJbM2g/4/)

Or

```
/^((?:-|^)\d{5}){8}$/m
```

To be more specific with hyphen delimiters.

Comment: `-25686-47362-04822-08149-48999-28161-15124-63556`, please notice starting `-`

Comment: That would match, but the OP did not specify that extra `-` were an option... Unclear if that is even an issue.